# Infinite intersection of closed Hilbert subspaces whose finite intersection is infinite-dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, complete-spaces, separable-spaces

I'm working in the setting of complex, separable, infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces and I came out with the following statement which, intuitively, seems to be true to me, though I haven't found a proof or a counterexample.

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space as above, and let $A_n$ be a sequence of closed subspaces such that $A_n^{\perp}$ has dimension $m \geq 1$ fixed for all $n \geq 1$. Moreover, assume that:

$$ \bigcap_{n=1}^{N} A_n  $$

is infinite dimensional for all $N$. Is it true that:

$$ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \neq 0$$

I thought of constructing a nested subsequence $B_n$ of closed sets of $A_n$ such that the diameter of $B_n$ tends to $0$ and all $x \in B_n$ satisfies $\|  x \|  =1$, so that we could apply Cantor's intersection Theorem and conclude that $\exists x :$

$$ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = \lbrace x \rbrace$$

Then, since $x$ cannot be $0$ by hypothesis, the infinite intersection of all $A_n$ must be at least one-dimensional.

However, I have not found any sequence $B_n$ as above. Maybe we might take the closure of a basis set for $A_1$ and construct a basis for each $A_n$ removing the "unnecessary" vectors, and take $B_n$ to be the closure of these sets?

Answer (score 3):

Counterexample:
take $H=\ell^2$, and $A_n=\{x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\in\ell^2: x_1=\ldots=x_n=0\}$
,then each $A_n$ is closed, with $\dim(A_n^{\perp})=n\ge1$, and any finite intersection among them is an infinite dimensional.

If $x\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$, and $x_k\neq0$, then $x\notin A_k, A_{k+1}, \ldots$, yielding a contradiction, thus no coordinate in x can be non-zero, which means the intersection can only be $0$

Comment: Alright, but I asked for the case where $A_n^\perp$ all have the *same* fixed dimension $m$, not a dimension that changes with $n$

Comment: then you may take $A_n=\{x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\in\ell^2: x_n=0\}$, in such case $A_n^{\perp}=1$ for all $n$. If $x_k\neq0$, then $x_k\notin A_k$, thus the same argument still apply, and the intersection has to be $0$

Comment: Oh, right, thanks!